# BugzScout in hosted Fogbugz

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand, bugzscout

Is it possible to use BugzScout in the fogcreek-hosted version of Fogbugz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can!

[The documentation](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/315/bugzscout-to-capture-errors) is on the FogBugz Knowledge Exchange. The sample code that ships for the for-your-server version of FogBugz is available for download [here](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?W741).

Comment: Note that you always need to use HTTPS with FogBugz On Demand.